# Symfony2 Validate on route exists

Tags: php, symfony

I have entity with some properties. The common fields are: `url` and `isRoute`.
When property

```
isRoute == true
```

the `url` property is transformed to a route. If

```
isRoute == false
```

it will remain a url.

When the form is submitted, I want to validate the `url` property is a route or not. Where I can do it? Create custom constraint for this field? What is the best variant?

Comment: Custom constraint seems like a sensible way to have field dependent validation. You should show what you have so far. It'll help to better understand the question and to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: I created Custom Constraint like a service with Router dependency and it's work. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @hasumedic Can you post this as an answer that trauma may accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) seems like a sensible way to have field dependent validation. You only need to create a class with your validation logic which can receive the Router [as a dependency](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies). With this dependency you can then check wether the field is a Route or not and add a violation otherwise.